# Apollo GraphQL cache for common data in different queries?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a web based application with two graphql queries that have some data in common. The first query `FullProject` is more or less a very broad "lets pull all data that the client might need" and contains many nested resources. For this question the important thing is that it also pulls in loads of users:

```
query FullProject($id: ID!) {
  projects(input: {filter: {id: $id}}) {
    nodes {
      id
      name
      relatedUsers {
        id
        name
      }
      # Many more
    }
  }
}
```

The second query is used to populate a list of users:

```
query NameUser($id: ID!) {
  users(input: {filter: {id: $id}}) {
    nodes {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

When I check the GraphQL cache (using the [Apollo Developer tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/apollo-developer-tools/)) after running `FullProject` I can see that the data has been properly normalized and I have entries like:

```
User:1
  name:A
---
User:2
  name:B
```

When I however run the `NameUser` query this always results in one new request for each user. After the first request for a user the cache properly kicks in, but this still means that I am ending up with possibly hundreds of queries for data that is technically already part of the cache (albeit via a different query). I was hoping that the Apollo Client would be able to leverage the cache even for different top-level queries. Am I doing something wrong or is my assumption incorrect?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects-using-field-policy-read-functions

Comment: Wow, how could I not see that ..? Feel free to change your comment into an answer, this seems to be exactly the issue that I am having.